# c++. Цикл самопроизвольно выходит за границы массива

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Кусок программы, которая должна строить график по точкам. N - кол-во узлов. a,b - начальная и конечная точка. h - шаг. Нашел проблему, поэтому немного свел код к тренировочному. Суть в том, что при N >= 100 в массив заносится не N элементов, а N+1 и из-за этого вылазит ошибка. В чем дело?

```
double a = -5, b = 5, h;
double N = 50;  
double *m;
int i = 0;  

h = (b - a)/N;

m = new double[N];

for (double x = a; x < b; x += h)
{       
    m[i] = i;   

    cout << i << " " << m[i] << endl;
    i++;
}
cout << "и i конеч = "  << i << endl;
```

N=50

[image: N=50]

N=100 или более

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перепишите свой код так:

```
cout << i << " " << m[i] << "  x = " << setprecision(20) << setw(20) << x <<  endl;
```

и при `N = 100` вы увидите, что значение `x` при `i==100` оказывается равным `4.9999999999999973355`, а не `5`, а значение `h = 0.10000000000000000555`. Грубо говоря, число с плавающей точкой - это приближение с помощью суммы дробей вида `1/2^n`, так что понятно, что далеко не любое дробное число может быть представлено переменной типа `double` точно...

При вычислениях с плавающей точкой любое сравнение всегда следует считать *приближенным*, а там, где вы работаете с по своей природе целочисленными данными - те же индексы массива - не заменяйте их на числа с плавающей точкой. Используйте, так сказать, *естественные типы* для своих объектов.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно было делать цикл по вещественной переменной. Перепишите на целочисленную.

```
for(size_t i=0;i<N;++i)
{       
    m[i] = i;   

    cout << i << " " << m[i] << endl;        
}
```

## Объяснение

Любые вычисления с вещественными числами выполняются с погрешностью, так как не все числа можно представить в виде конечной дроби со знаменателем 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (double x=a, int i=0; i<N; x += h, i++){
 m[i] = i;   
 cout << i << " " << m[i] << endl;
}
```